# how to call sequential action in AndEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

Is there any way to use something like CCSequence in cocos2d-android ? 
In my android game development I want sequential actions one after another like CCSequense in cocos2d-android.
please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

AndEngine only supports a path sequence. You can implement the others yourself using [EntityModifier](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/modifier/EntityModifier.java).